# Show tabs in a second bar using Actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, tabs, split, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem showing tabs with ActionBarSherlock. I have copied the example code of actionbarsherlock demos in my own aplication, if I run the application in a 7'' display like Nexus 7, tabs appear at the same bar as the title. But if I run the ABS sample in the same device tabs appears in a different bar.

What's wrong with my application?

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ResourcesCompat;
import com.mbal.misseries.R;

public class ProvaDeFragments extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);


        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

It's shown like this:

[From my application](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-dGTj4s8A7cG8zY01TS1dXVzg/edit?usp=sharing)

But if I run the sample ABS code appears like this:

[ABS Sample Demo](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz-dGTj4s8A7aThiSTZkYzd6ajA/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong, except testing it on a device with enough room. ;-)

Per the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) documentation in the Google developer site:

> When you want to provide navigation tabs in an activity, using the
>   action bar's tabs is a great option (instead of using TabWidget),
>   because the system adapts the action bar tabs for different screen
>   sizes—placing them in the main action bar when the screen is
>   sufficiently wide, or in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action
>   bar") when the screen is too narrow, as shown in figures 9 and 10.

If you make longer tabs, add more actions to the bar, and/or test it in a thinner view (portrait on a mobile phone, for example), it should break it out to a second bar automatically.

Note the view in their examples (copied below) the second one that stacks them is much more narrow than the first.

Figure 9

[image: figure 9]

Figure 10

[image: figure 10]